# getElement não declara o objeto (VBA) .IE

Tags: vba, excel-vba

preciso de uma ajudinha em um codigo, VBA interação em IE, uso uma pagina para extrair relatorios diarios, e atualmente esse pagina sofreu uma atualização de versão, meus codigos estão quase todos funcionado porem o codigo que teria que acionar um botão para gerar um relatório de informações, não esta funcionado, tentei varias formas mas sem sucesso, meu conhecimento é ainda, acho que e coisa simples, mas eu não consegui finalizar.

codigo da pagina IE.

```html
<button title="Iniciar" class="sapMBarChild sapMBtn sapMBtnBase sapMBtnInverted" id="__bar2-btnGo" aria-describedby="__text13" data-sap-ui="__bar2-btnGo"><span class="sapMBtnEmphasized sapMBtnHoverable sapMBtnInner sapMBtnText sapMFocusable sapMIE" id="__bar2-btnGo-inner"><span class="sapMBtnContent" id="__bar2-btnGo-content">Iniciar</span><span class="sapMBtnFocusDiv"></span></span></button>
```

Cod VBA IE.

```
'IDENTIFICA A DATA DA REQUISIÇÃO (FINAL) ' ok funcionado

Set objCollection = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
For Each objElement In objCollection
    If objElement.ID = "__xmlview0--filterDtEndRequest-inner" Then objElement.innerText = Data2
Next objElement                                  '

'IDENTIFICA O BOTÃO PARA EXECUTAR ' Com erro abaixo
'*************************************************************

Set objCollection = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("button")
For Each objElement In objCollection
    If (objElement.getAttribute("title") = "Iniciar") Then objElement.Click
Next objElement
```

Comment: Codigo html

<button title="Iniciar" class="sapMBarChild sapMBtn sapMBtnBase sapMBtnInverted" id="__bar2-btnGo" aria-describedby="__text13" data-sap-ui="__bar2-btnGo"><span class="sapMBtnEmphasized sapMBtnHoverable sapMBtnInner sapMBtnText sapMFocusable sapMIE" id="__bar2-btnGo-inner"><span class="sapMBtnContent" id="__bar2-btnGo-content">Iniciar</span><span class="sapMBtnFocusDiv"></span></span></button> )

Comment: Favor [edit] a questão com o código html

Comment: danieltakeshi ajuda este formato?

Answer (score 0):

#### HTML

Adicionando um JS no código HTML para verificar se o mesmo foi clicado:

```js
function toggleText() {
  var text = document.getElementById("demo");
  if (text.style.display === "none") {
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test HTML</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p id='demo' style='display: none'>Hello Teste</p> 
  <button title="Iniciar" class="sapMBarChild sapMBtn sapMBtnBase sapMBtnInverted" id="__bar2-btnGo" aria-describedby="__text13" data-sap-ui="__bar2-btnGo" onclick="toggleText()"><span class="sapMBtnEmphasized sapMBtnHoverable sapMBtnInner sapMBtnText sapMFocusable sapMIE" id="__bar2-btnGo-inner"><span class="sapMBtnContent" id="__bar2-btnGo-content">Iniciar</span><span class="sapMBtnFocusDiv"></span></span>
  </button>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

#### Solução

É possível clicar no botão encontrando a tag do mesmo, que precisa ser "button" e se o texto for iniciar, porém utilizando a função [Trim()](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ltrim-rtrim-and-trim-functions). Pois o texto está com um espaço e é "Iniciar ".

```
'Declara função Sleep
#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr) 'For 64 Bit Systems
#Else
    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) 'For 32 Bit Systems
#End If

Public Sub ClicarBotao()
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim url As String
    Dim myPoints As String

    url = "http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/TmODUSMPPAxswW7pqyfV/"
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate url
    End With
    
    EsperaIE IE, 2000

    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
    Set Doc = IE.document

    For Each elemento In Doc.body.getElementsByTagName("button")
        Debug.Print elemento.Type
        Debug.Print elemento.innerText
        If Trim(elemento.innerText) = "Iniciar" And elemento.Type = "submit" Then
            elemento.Click
        End If
    Next elemento
    Set IE = Nothing

End Sub

Public Sub EsperaIE(IE As Object, Optional time As Long = 250)
    'Código de: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808000/run-time-error-91-object-variable-or-with-block-variable-not-set
    Dim i As Long
    Do
        Sleep time
        Debug.Print CStr(i) & vbTab & "Ready: " & CStr(IE.readyState = 4) & _
                    vbCrLf & vbTab & "Busy: " & CStr(IE.Busy)
        i = i + 1
    Loop Until IE.readyState = 4 Or Not IE.Busy
End Sub
```